# Proof: A loopless graph $G$ is $k$-chromatic ($\chi(G) = k$) $\Rightarrow G$ has a $k$-critical subgraph $H$.

Tags: graph-theory

Proof: A loopless graph $G$ is $k$-chromatic ($\chi(G) = k$) $\Rightarrow G$ has a $k$-critical subgraph $H$.

Idea:
Let $G$ be a graph with no loops:

Start by removing any isolated vertices (if $G$ has an edge) or remove all but one vertix (if $G$ has no edge)  - the graph obtained has the same chromatic number as $G$. Then remove edges from $G$ until any edge would lower the chromatic number. Call this subgraph $H$.

Let $S$ be a proper subgraph of $H$ obtained by deleting some set $V$ of vertices and set $E$ of edges. Removing any edge from $H$ yields a proper subgraph with lower chromatic number. Removing any vertix from $H$ yields a proper subgraph of $H$ with at least one edge removed. Thus the proper subgraph obtained has chromatic number less than $G$. Repeating to delete vertices and edges can only yield a lower chromatic number to for the resulting proper subgraph.

Is this proof right ?

http://www.math.sinica.edu.tw/post-doctor/hbchen/13_1_2.pdf

Consider a graph $G$ with an isolated vertix. Then the subgraph obtained from $G$ by removing edges has a proper subgroup, with this isolated vertix removed, that has the same chromatic number as $G$ ?

Comment: The idea is there. It needs refinement. It is an inductive argument, so make explicit.

Comment: I'm convinced it works and that you can stop at "Call this subgraph $H$", as it seems obvious that $H$ has to be k-critical.  However, if $H$ is required to be a $proper$ subgraph of $G$ (as in your pdf), then there would be a problem if $G$ is itself k-critical.  Because then, the $H$ you find is $G$, which is not a proper subgraph of $G$.  In fact, no proper subgraph $H$ of $G$ can be k-critical in this case, as by definition $\chi(H) < k$.